# Add suffix to file name AFTER extension (batch mode)

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

Hey I know that this question has been asked in one form or another, but all the ones I could find were for java script, or C, or some other coding language.

I am looking for a command line argument (able to be executed from command prompt) that will let me add (.)__ meta __ to the end of all (multiple) file name extensions in a folder.

Example, I want to rename these files:

```
database.db
userkey.mb
pdox.net
apphistory.px
keyfile1.xg0
keyfile2.xg1
keyfile3.xg2
clock.yg0
timer.yg1
```

to this:

```
database.db.__meta__
userkey.mb.__meta__
pdox.net.__meta__
apphistory.px.__meta__
keyfile1.xg0.__meta__
keyfile2.xg1.__meta__
keyfile3.xg2.__meta__
clock.yg0.__meta__
timer.yg1.__meta__
```

Is it possible to write a code that is capable of this?
if there is any software to do this let me know. I have looked and so far have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply rename them

```
ren *.* *.*._meta_
```

Comment: +1, Believe it or not, there is an even shorter command that works. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19611610/1012053) :)

Answer (score 1):

An even shorter command :-)

```
ren * *?.__meta__
```

If you should ever find you want to later remove the extension from all files:

```
ren * *.
```

Or if you want to only remove `.__meta__` extensions

```
ren *.__meta__ *.
```

For an explanation as to why the above commands work, see [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090)

Comment: There is a little difference. Neither better nor worse. Different. When files have no extension (`data.`), your command renames it to `data.__meta__` , mine to `data..__meta__` . Depending of latter needs, one or the other should be used. Yor answer about wildcards

Comment: @MCND - Good catch regarding difference. I don't understand the last sentence in your comment.

Comment: Bad copy and paste from original comment placed where it shouldn't. It should say  `Your answer about wildcards in rename command is awesome`.

Comment: @MCND - Thanks! I wish it hadn't been moved to SuperUser. I think it would get a lot more traffic here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -exec mv {} {}.__meta__ \;
```

Answer (score 0):

=========================

Answer from JoeG314, 2013Oct28, to the original question from Kazankoph on 2013Oct27:

Below is a link to file ADD1EXT.BAT--it's simple to use with no complex syntax to be typed.

It's documented, so you will know how to run it
--it will do what Kazankoph requested; and it allows for spaces in filenames
and multiple extensions (myfile.ext1.ext2.ext3.ext4) on a filename.

Save that file on your disk and then execute it (ADD1EXT) at a DOS prompt.

Link to ADD1EXT.BAT:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9GgUicCNu_zQkVwTFA1Z2w2aVk/edit?usp=sharing

==========================

Comment: You shouldn't have copied the text verbatim, but rather linked to the original answer or flagged as duplicate.